# Use a For to move from cells

Tags: string, excel, vba, variables, for-loop

i need in my Macro is: From a Worksheet (ex: W1) select a whole cell, and the result paste it in another worksheet (W2) cell (A1), then pick another column of W1 and sum it and paste it in A2 and so on. 
What i've wrote is:

```
Sub SumasTbf() 
Dim Seleccion As Range 
Dim Suma 


Worksheets("hoja2").Activate 
Set Seleccion = Range(ActiveSheet.Range("B1"), ActiveSheet.Range("B1").End(xlDown)) 
Suma = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Seleccion) 
Worksheets("hoja3").Range("F1") = Suma
```

Now im thinking in using a FOR to move the range B1 to C1 but i dont know how to move the B to C, can you help me plz! in case of working with rows it would be "B"& x ?? (another question)... waiting for an answer

Comment: What are you doing this in? Microsoft Excel?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Sub SumasTbf()
Dim myRange As Range
Dim Suma As Long, lastRow As Long, i as Long

For i = 2 To 10 'This will loop from column B to J
    With Worksheets("hoja2")
        lastRow = .Cells(1, i).End(xlDown).Row
        Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(lastRow, i))
        Suma = WorksheetFunction.Sum(myRange)
    End With

    'Now, let's record the sum in A1, then A2, etc.
    ' use i-1 since i starts at 2
    Worksheets("hoja3").Cells(i - 1, 1) = Suma
Next i
End Sub
```

Mainly, when wanting to iterate over ranges, you can use `Range(Cells([row #],[column #]),Cells([row #],[column #]))`.  Then just use a variable to loop (`i`).

Also, I changed `seleccion`, since I assume that's also the way VBA uses an active selection.  I changed it to `myRange` so there's no potential confusion.